# How to set Yii::app()->user->name

Tags: yii

I tried

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'TEST';
}
```

in UserIdentity.php but it doesn't seem to change the value of Yii::app()->user->name

Comment: While this question is for Yii1, I wrote an answer for how to do it in Yii2 properly. Just in case anyone searching Google for this lands here, read this for Yii2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415388/yii2-how-to-get-the-current-username-or-name-from-yiiapp-user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the class `UserIdentity` that you defined you'll need to set a new state by using `setState(name, value)` method.

For example in the method `authenticate` if the user is good:

```
//if the user is good (good login and good password)
$this->_id=$record->id;
$this->setState('name', $record->name);
$this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
```

Then you will be able to call `Yii::app()->user->name`

- [A complete example in the Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class)
- [The setState() documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseUserIdentity#setState-detail)