# Yii2 - How to get the current username or name from Yii::$app->user?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-user

How do you add, or get, variables using `Yii::$app->user->something`?

I don't want to get them through `identity`. I want to make specific ones accessible through `user`.

For example, I want to get the current logged in user's username and name:

```
\Yii::$app->user->username
```

or

```
\Yii::$app->user->name
```

Comment: the answer for your question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27858658/3600691)

Comment: @user3600691 - Please look at [the page you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858575/get-the-name-of-the-user-in-yii2/27858658#27858658) again. I also answered the question right below it, linking to this page! ThePeach's answer uses `identity`. I already know how, if you look at my answer on this page. I am showing how to `extend` the `User` component to add whatever you want to `Yii::$app->user->whatever`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While other topics here on SO offer a chincy hack solution, or to simply fetch it through `Yii::$app->user->identity`, I am going to show you how to do it properly. You can bend Yii2 to your will, by virtually extending everything!

I normally work in the "advanced" app, but I am going to just use the "basic" app as a reference for everyone. I assume those who are using the "advanced" app know the differences and understand namespaces.

**Namespace Crash Course:** In basic, you have `namespace app\path\to`. This is where the file is located. For example, you have ContactForm.php located in the app root `models` directory, so it's namespace is `app\models`. In advanced, you have multiple apps (frontend & backend), so the app root is different, thus you have `frontend` as one app root, and `backend` as another. The models directory in the advanced app is at "frontend/models" and it's namespace is `frontend\models`. -- So anywhere you see "app" in the namespace, you can replace it with `frontend` or `backend` for the "advanced" template.

---

### Solution

First, we need to modify our app's config file to override the default User component's class. I will leave out anything not related, so you keep your `identityClass` defined, I just am not showing it. We are simply adding to, not replacing, the config. Also, where I show `frontend/something`, the same can be done for `backend/something`. I just am not going to repeat both over and over again...

Basic (`config/web.php`) -or- Advanced (`frontend/config/main.php`)

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\User', // extend User component
    ],
],
```

*Remember: If you are using the advanced template, replace `app` with `frontend` or `backend`!*

I also want to point out, that you will need to create the "components" directory if you haven't done so. This is where many people add their custom Classes. Whether it be your own helper class, or extending a base Yii component (such as extending `yii\web\Controller`).

Create a new file in your `components` directory named `User.php`. In that file, place the following code:

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use Yii;

/**
 * Extended yii\web\User
 *
 * This allows us to do "Yii::$app->user->something" by adding getters
 * like "public function getSomething()"
 *
 * So we can use variables and functions directly in `Yii::$app->user`
 */
class User extends \yii\web\User
{
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->user->identity->name;
    }
}
```

*Note: `username` and `name` must be valid column names in your database's user table!*

So now we can use this in our controller, view, anywhere.. Let's test it out. In `views/site/index.php`, add this to the bottom of the page:

```
<?= \Yii::$app->user->name ?>
<?= \Yii::$app->user->username ?>
```

If all is good, and you have values in the user table for name and username, they should be printed on to the page :)

Comment: Why is getting data directly from `Yii::$app->user->identity` not the proper way? What are the downsides?