# Getting the username instead of the user id - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my form I wanna get the username instead of the user_id, I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object", how do I properly get the Username from the user table?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->textInput(
[
    //'value' => Yii::$app->user->getId(),
    'value' => $model->user->username,
    'readonly' => true,
    'style' => 'width:400px'
]
  )?>
```

Here's the model of this form

```
public function getUserType(){
  //Related model Class Name
  //related column name as select
  return $this->hasOne(User::className() ,['id' => 'user_id'])->select('type')->scalar();
}
```

Comment: What is your `$model`? Do you have relation to `user` in this model?

Comment: What do you mean by what is my $model, yes the user model has a relation in this model

Comment: You're trying to get relation by `$model->user` - so i'm asking, what's exacly is your `$model` (which class), and is in this `$model` - do you have defined relation to `User`?

Comment: `var_dump($model->user)` and check what's in there first.

Comment: @DEarTh it says null.

Comment: @Yupik The request model has a relation to the user model I added the function that has been generated by gii

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415388/yii2-how-to-get-the-current-username-or-name-from-yiiapp-user?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @DEarTH thank you I've finally solve it!

Answer (score 1):

You need the following relation in your code

```
public function getUser(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

And your code should work.

I dont think what your are doing is correct, you are making an input binded with your user ID which contain your username. When the form is submitted Yii will try to load the username string in you user_id property. If the username and the user_id aren't the same thing this will cause a validation error.

The problem arise from the fact that you are using an input binded with a form for display purpuse. You should create an input without the form like

```
$options = ['readonly' => true, 'style' => 'width:400px']    
Html::inputText( "username", $model->user->username, $options)
```

or just remove the input and write the value inside a div.